# Не работает Java код

Tags: java

Дорогие друзья! Помогите, пожалуйста, решить вопрос с данным отрезком кода. Жалуется на `NoSuchAlgorithmException` и `UnsupportedEncodingException`.

```
private void func198i (){
        String x0 = this.mc.session.sessionId;
        x0 = getHash(x0+"protect");
        this.mc.session.sessionId = x0;
    }

    public static String getHash(String str){
        MessageDigest m;
        try {
            m = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            m.reset();
            try {
                m.update(str.getBytes("utf-8"));
                String s2 = new BigInteger(1,m.digest()).toString(16);
                while(s2.length() < 32 ){
                    s2 = "0"+s2;
                }
                return s2;
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                return e.toString();
            }
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            return e.toString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Уберите строку

```
m.reset();
```

И замените

```
m.update(str.getBytes("utf-8"));
```

на

```
m.update(str.getBytes("UTF8"));
```

Comment: error: cannot find symbol
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
symbol: class UnsupportedEncodingException
location: class NetClientHandler
src\minecraft\net\minecraft\client\multiplayer\NetClientHandler.java:1802: error: cannot find symbol
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

Comment: > src\minecraft\net\minecraft\client\multiplayer\NetClientHandler.java:1802: error: cannot find symbol

Что же это может быть?)